# How to hide the complete hover animation

Tags: html, css, animation

Me and my friend recently have a problem with a portfolio case, the hove over animation doesnt go back properly to the original picture. How can we fix this? 
See: [The website](http://rick.arjendendulk.com)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="case">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="case_content">
            <div class="case_text">
                <h3>Market Download Buttons</h3>
                <h4>UI Design</h4>
            </div>
            <a class="venobox" href="img/2.jpg"><p class="balk">View Dribbble Shot</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.cases {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.case {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.case_content {
  background-color: rgba(54,54,62,0.99);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.case_text {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 0 0 5%;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the problem? What do I need to hover? As everything seemed normal.

Comment: I don't understand either. There isn't even any hover related CSS in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hover option in `CSS`

```
.case {
  ..
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  ..
}

.case:hover, .case:hover .case_content {
    display: block;
}

.case_content {
    ..
    display: none;
    ..
}
```

Comment: This is ok? but can this block that is springing in right now been faded in? or isnt that possible @holpducki

Comment: @ArjenDenDulk put the `transitions` from `.case_content` inside `.case`